# Multi-label graph segmentation

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, image-segmentation

I'm working on a problem where I need to find relationships between objects. This problem is modeled as a graph, where all the objects are represented as vertices and their relationships as weighted edges.

Where there's 2 objects related and connected with an edge, there are 2 metrics, one of them is an attractive force and the other a repulsive one (it can be the case where any two objects don't attract nor repel each other)

At the end, I have a tiny weighted graph with about 100 - 500 vertices, with about 3-6 connections each.

I want to automatically split the graph into segments where each one of them contains groups of objects attracting among themselves. There is not previous knowledge on how many groups there should be nor which objects belong to which groups.

**I'm looking for a suitable algorithm to do this.**

An obvious answer would be to use [graphcut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem), the problem is that I need more than a single cut (but don't know how many of them) and there is not previous knowledge of where the *source* and the *sink* might be.

I'm actually looking for some more like [Efficient Graph-Based Image Segmentation](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~dph/papers/seg-ijcv.pdf). The problem here is that my graph is significantly smaller than the graph you would get out of a relatively small image (you can imagine segmenting a 20x20 px image into groups of 1-10 px, at that scale the frequency goes up (imagine segmenting high frequency noise) and the algorithm doesn't behave as expected.

Is there a suitable algorithm to achieve this?

Any c++ implementation would be useful as well

Comment: Do you want to find connected components? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29

Comment: Something like that but not exactly. On the graph all the vertices are connected either directly or indirectly to each other (there is a single component). Let's say that I need to split the graph into components where the edges between nodes have some discrepancy and keep components where the connections among them have some "attracting force"

Comment: if you don't get an answer here, it would be wortwhile to ask https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ regarding the algorithm

Comment: That'd be probably a good idea :)

Comment: I guess that a reasonable first cut at a concrete objective would be to maximize the sum of the inter-cluster repulsive forces plus the intra-cluster attractive forces. Unfortunately, I expect that this and other reasonable formulations will be NP-hard to optimize. The input graph is small enough that you could consider methods based on semidefinite programming, but I'm not sure whether these theoretical methods work well in practice.